# Can "neither" be placed at the beginning of the sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions, sentence-starts

Which of the following is grammatical?

> - Trust neither a new friend nor an old enemy.
> - Neither trust a new friend nor an old enemy.

Comment: would this be okay? Either Cindy or Felicia wants to rearrange the desks so that **she** can sit by the window. Or would it be this, Either Cindy or Felicia wants to rearrange the desks so that **they** can sit by the window.

Answer (score 3):

Either is correct, as "nor" follows a [negative statement](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-use-nor) in both cases. For example "Neither borrower nor lender be" from Shakespeare's Hamlet...one could do worse than depend on Shakespeare ;-)

Comment: Sometimes *neither* is used in the sense of *nor*.  For example: *“You should not venture out before dawn. Neither should you do so after dusk.”*

Comment: @tchrist did you mean to comment on my answer or on the original post? Not sure if I was implying that nor is the only option..

Comment: -1 because this answer fails to acknowledge the error in the second of the OP's examples.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly place *neither* at the start of a sentence. The problem with your sentence doing so is that it suffers from [faulty parallelism](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/Faulty-Parallelism.htm) whereby the *neither* precedes a verb and the parallel *nor* precedes a noun phrase.

The words *Neither trust a new friend ...* lead the reader to expect a continuation such as *nor lend him any money* or *nor tell him your deepest secret*. When you thwart the reader's expectations in such a way you have written a [garden-path sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence).

---

EDIT: 
On reflection, it could be claimed that the verb *trust* is implicit after *nor* and can be elided. At any rate the sentence is not an egregrious *garden path*.

Comment: I think you were right before the edit. Your reader may backtrack and insert the *trust* to make sense of the sentence; but you should not make your reader do your own job.

Comment: I agree that considerate writers take care to avoid forcing their readers to backtrack. In the OP's sentence the parallel structures are very short and do not lead the reader very far down the wrong path - unlike some of the examples collected by the esteemed linguists on Language Log: http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/index.php?s=garden+path.

Answer (score 1):

An inscription on the James Farley Post Office in New York City reads:

**Neither snow nor rain nor heat nor gloom of night stays these couriers from the swift completion of their appointed rounds.[1]**

This phrase was a translation by Prof. George Herbert Palmer, Harvard University, from an ancient Greek work of Herodotus describing the Persian system of mounted postal carriers c. 500 B.C.E. The inscription was added to the building by William Mitchell Kendall of the architectural firm of McKim, Mead & White, the building's architects. It derives from a quote from Herodotus' Histories, referring to the courier service of the ancient Persian Empire...

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Postal_Service_creed

Answer (score 0):

If 'neither' is followed by a verb 'nor' should also be followed by a verb.  E.g.  Audience should neither stand up nor make a noise.  Here, if one writes "Neither audience should stand up, or make a noise" is incorrect.

Yes, 'neither' can be used at the start.
Neither be an emperor, nor be a beggar.  (It is like "be neither an emperor nor a beggar.")